# Why does CSS text-align:center; not work?

Tags: css

This is code

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>웹 프로그래밍 기초</h1>
<img src="images/CB9A982F-A812-486E-A9E6-30E6ACFA916D.jpeg" alt="HTML5">
<h2>2.2 CSS </h2>
<h3>글꼴과 텍스트 </h3>
<P> 글꼴과 텍스트 스타일을 바꿔봅시다</P>
```

I save this in Visual Studio. But preview doesn't apply the css texts(like text align, height, letterspacing..)

plz help me

Comment: What are you expecting to be centred because the h1 text is centred and that's the only thing I can see you have applied the text align to

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align: center` style is working correctly on the h1 in your snippet, If you want to apply the `text-align: center` on all of the elements, you can use a parent container element for all of the elements and add the `text-align: center` style to it. You can see the result in the following. 
Hope this helps you :)

```html
 <html>
 <body>
 <style>
 html {
      font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }

    img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 2;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #container {
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="container">
    <h1>웹 프로그래밍 기초</h1>
    <img src="images/CB9A982F-A812-486E-A9E6-30E6ACFA916D.jpeg" alt="HTML5">
    <h2>2.2 CSS </h2>
    <h3>글꼴과 텍스트 </h3>
    <P> 글꼴과 텍스트 스타일을 바꿔봅시다</P>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```